# RecordNotFound with accepts_nested_attributes_for and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I get

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Client with ID=3 for Order with ID=

when trying to submit an Order form for an existing client.  This happens through the form or the console by typing:

```
Order.new(:client_attributes => { :id => 3 })
```

**payment_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @order, :url => checkout_purchase_url(:secure => true) do |f| %>

        <%= f.inputs "Personal Information" do %>

            <%= f.semantic_fields_for :client do |ff| %>
                <%= ff.input :first_name %>
                <%= ff.input :last_name %>              
                <!-- looks like semantic_fields_for auto-inserts a hidden field for client ID -->
            <% end %>

        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Order.rb**:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client, :reject_if => :check_client

  def check_client(client_attr)
    if _client = Client.find(client_attr['id'])
      self.client = _client
      return true
    else
      return false
    end    
  end
end
```

The `reject_if` idea came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164185/accepts-nested-attributes-for-to-link-to-existing-record-not-create-a-new-one) but I logged the method and it's not even being called!  It doesn't matter what its name is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want a new Order with an existing client, without modifying the client, you need to assign the id.

```
Order.new(client_id: 3)
```

This is another way to do this without overloading the `client_attributes=` method and cleanest

The new Order now has the client with ID 3

If you also want to update ant client's attributes you must add the  `client_attributes`, for example:

```
Order.new(client_id: 3, client_attributes: { id: 3, last_order_at: Time.current })
```

See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7256 from 2012.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The Rails way to solve the OP is to use `client_id`. So either 1) set `client_id` on the frontend before passing to the backend or 2) assign `client_id` to the id from the `client_attributes` on the backend. After either of these approaches, accepts_nested_attributes_for will work.

Comment: OK thanks. I've changed this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Note: Feb 2020**

Since I'm starting to get downvotes on this *8 years later*, adding this note.  While this was the original solution I went with 8 years ago, [a better one has been proposed by MatayoshiMariano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45328528/805003) (5 years after my OP).

**My Original Fix**

Fixed the issue by overloading the client_attributes= method, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic):

```
  def client_attributes=(client_attrs)    
    self.client = Client.find_or_initialize_by_id(client_attrs.delete(:id))
    self.client.attributes = client_attrs
  end
```

Comment: Doesn't this end up creating another Client even if it finds a client by id?

Comment: This is not the Rails way. The issue in the OP has existed for a decade and the solution is to use `client_id`. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7256

Although I appreciate there may be value in this approach, I have learned from experience that sticking to the intended way for Rails to work has rewards and deviating brings lots of problems. So I strongly suggest using `client_id` and not overriding `client_attributes=`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have has_many relationship, this will work. Tested on Rails 6.0.2

```
  def clients_attributes =(attributes)
    # Get IDs for any clients that already exist.
    client_ids = attributes.values.map { |a| a[:id] }.compact

    # Now find them all and move them to this section.
    clients << Client.find(client_ids)

    # Update them with standard `accepts_nested_attributes_for` behaviour.
    super attributes
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error creating a new Thing for existing model with **has_many** and **belongs_to** relations.

Fixed it by adding a hidden field for the id of the existing model, for instance User, to the form.

```
= form.input :user_id, as: :hidden
```

Then new Thing was created without the error.