# Adding existing has_many records to new record with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

The error "Couldn't find Item with ID=123 for Payment with ID=" occurs when adding existing Item models to a new Payment model. This is in a has_many relationship and using accepts_nested_attributes_for.

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
  ...

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payment
  ...
```

The payment and item models are hypothetical but the problem is real. I need to associate the Items with the Payment (as I do in the new action) before saving the Payment (done in the create action). The user needs to modify attributes on the Items as they create the Payment (adding a billing code would be an example).

Specifically, the error occurs in the controller's create action:

```
# payments_controller.rb

def new
  @payment = Payment.new
  @payment.items = Item.available # where(payment_id: nil)
end

def create
  @payment = Payment.new payment_params # <-- error happens here
  ...
end

def payment_params
  params.require(:payment).permit( ..., [items_attributes: [:id, :billcode]])
end
```

`lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:543:in 'raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!'` is immediately prior to it in the callstack. It is curious that ActiveRecord is including  payment_id as part of the search criteria.

For the sake of being complete, the form looks something like this...

```
form_for @payment do |f|
   # payment fields ...
   fields_for :items do |i|
     # item fields
```

and it renders the Items correctly on the new action. The params passed through the form look like this:

```
{ "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"...",
  "payment"=>{
    "items_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{"billcode"=>"123", "id"=>"192"}
    },
  }
}
```

If there is a better way to approach this that doesn't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Hey, I think you should modify your payment_params to allow :id in item_attributes like this: `params.require(:payment).permit( ..., [items_attributes: [:id, :billcode]])`. This way, the right available item can be extracted from the database. Let me know if this works.
`

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's in my code just not this question. You can see it in the params hash that is getting passed back. I'll fix the code snippet. Appreciate you catching that.

Comment: Is your `payment_id` in your `items` is saving properly?

Comment: It never gets that far. The Payment model is still a new record at the point when the error occurs.

Comment: Looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864501/recordnotfound-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-belongs-to/61905306#61905306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This confused me...

> "Adding existing records to a new record..."

So you have `Item 1, 2, 3`, and wish to associate them to a new `Product` object?

--

**Join Model**

The way to do this will be to use a `join model` ([`habtm`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)) rather than sending the data through [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

The bottom line is every time you create a new `Product` object, its associated `Item` objects can *only* be associated to that product:

```
#items table
id | product_id | information | about | item | created_at | updated_at
```

So if you're looking to use `existing` `Item` objects, how can you define *multiple* associations for them? The fact is you can't - you'll have to create an intermediary table / model, often cited as a `join model`:

[image]

```
#app/models/product.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

#app/models/item.rb
Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

#items_products (table)
item_id | product_id
```

--

**HABTM**

If you use a HABTM setup (as I have demonstrated above), it will allow you to add / delete from the [`collection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) your various objects have, as well as a sneaky trick where you can just add `Items` to a product using `item_ids`:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
Class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @product = Product.new(product_params)
      @product.save
   end

   private

   def product_params
       params.require(:product).permit(item_ids: [])
   end
end
```

If you then pass the param `item_ids[]` to your `create_method`, it will populate the `collection` for you.

If you want to add specific items to a `product`, or remove them, you may wish to do this:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
Class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def add
     @product = Product.find params[:id]
     @item = Item.find params[:item_id]

     @product.items << @item
     @product.items.delete params[:item_id]
   end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your thoughtful answer. You got the question right. I see your point with the HABTM (I'm very familiar) as being a workaround. I'll give it a couple more days before marking this 'accepted'. It seems like a shortcoming in AR to not allow existing child records. As a temporary fix, I split the items collection from the params, updated them and created the Payment separately and then reattached them.

Comment: I marked this as the selected answer because apparently changing the db schema is the only way get ActiveRecord to attach existing children to a new parent.

Answer (score 13):

I got this to work by just adding an `item_ids` collection to the params (in addition to the `items_attributes`).  You should just be able to massage your parameters in the controller to look like this

```
{ "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"...",
  "payment"=>{
    "item_ids"=>[192]
    "items_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{"billcode"=>"123", "id"=>"192"}
    },
  }
}
```

UPDATE 1: For some reason this only works if `item_ids` is before `items_attributes` in the hash.  Have not reviewed [Rails docs](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb) yet to figure out why.

Comment: This is actually pretty good. A lot of people posted more complicated solutions. I tried and works great. Updating the nested model and rendering validations in the form

Comment: Nice trick, what about saving an extra field such as position on the join table? Thanks!

Comment: Awsome! This is working for me!
Instead of using a hash inside `items_attributes`, an array of hashes can be used too.
Just like this:


    `items_attributes: [{ "billcode"=>"123", "id"=>"192 }]`